# Dynamically refreshing an image using ajax within Grails

Tags: ajax, grails, groovy

I have a web page where I need periodically update image based
on several conditions. For now I'm using this:

```
 <html>
   <head>
   <meta http-equiv="refresh" content="3">
   </head>
    <body>
        <img src="${createLink(controller:'advertisment',action:'viewImage',id:advertismentInstance.id)}"/>
    </body>
</html>
```

But it causes total reload of the web page, so I want it to be done
with Ajax (I'm also using Prototype framework which is default in Grails).

Provide with advertisment controller method:

```
 def viewImage = {
        log.info("before view Image")
        def adv = Advertisment.get(params.id)
        byte[] image = adv.fileContent
        response.outputStream << image
        log.info("after view Image")
    }
```

device controller method:

```
def showAdv =
    {
        log.info("showAdv start")

        def deviceInstance = Device.get(params.id)
        int totalNumberOfAdv = deviceInstance.advertisment.size();
        Random rand = new Random()
        int advToShow = rand.nextInt(totalNumberOfAdv+1) - 1;

        def advertismentInstance = deviceInstance.advertisment.toArray()[advToShow]
        if(advertismentInstance)
        {
            render(view: "image", model: [deviceInstance :deviceInstance,advertismentInstance: advertismentInstance])
        }
        else
        {
            flash.message = "${message(code: 'default.not.found.message', args: [message(code: 'advertisment.label', default: 'Advertisment'), params.id])}"
        }

        log.info("showAdv end")

    }
```

Comment: Yes, you can use some kind of ajax there. what exactly i've tried, and what your current problem?

Comment: Agreed with @splix, it might help to ask an actual question. "Any thoughts?" doesn't give us enough information about what you're trying to do.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Give your `<img/>` an id:

   ```
   <img id="foo" src="..."/><!-- keep the existing src -->
   ```
2. Remove the `<meta/>` that's refreshing the page.
3. Before the closing `</body>` tag, add this:

   ```
   <script>
   var img = document.getElementById('foo'); // id of image
   setInterval(function() {
       var stamp = new Date().getTime();
       img.setAttribute('src', img.getAttribute('src') + '?_=' + stamp);
   }, 3000);
   </script>
   ```
4. Update your `viewImage` action to actually do the randomization before rendering the image. This probably means combining parts of `showAdv` into `viewImage`.

Comment: Thank you for your reply, but id doesn't work as expected. It is always shows the same image, I have to call another method,so I tried smth like this:
<img src="${createLink(controller:'advertisment',action:'viewImage',id:advertismentInstance.id)}"/>
<img id ="foo" src="${createLink(controller:'device',action:'showAdv',id:deviceInstance.id)}"/>
In my logs I see that method showAdv from dev. controller is called and generated some image,
but on page nothing changes.

Comment: Did you use the timestamp at the end of the img src url?

Comment: Yes, I did as in your reply. In other words, I need to call showAdv method within Ajax with appropriate id(see above,device id always must be the same) and to refresh advertismentIn‌​stance.id (it must changes every 3 seconds) to show new image.

Comment: I guess I'm not sure, then. It might help to show the controller action (`advertisement/viewImage`) code to give us more context.

Comment: Hello, Rob! Thank you once again. I provided both methods for both controllers: I need to call showAdv with persistent device.id within Ajax. In your solution nothing changes because I'm always showing the same advertisment(id never changes), but in log file I can see that viewImage method is periodically called. So, I need somehow to modify my gsp page to call device/showAdv method to generate new advertisment. Is it possible? Thanks in advance.

Comment: I updated my answer with a step 4. I didn't elaborate much, but if you just have `viewImage` figure out the random id, you don't even need `showAdv`, unless I'm misunderstanding what you're trying to do.

Comment: Great,Rob! Thank you very,very much. Shame on me that I missed so simple solution...